# I need an Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If A is smaller or equal to 20 then if any condition in the brackets is fulfilled the product goes OUT, else it STAYS. * That is the core of the formula.*

`IF A<=20 THEN (IF B>=10% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`

**The full version if the formula**

`IF A<=20 THEN (IF B>=10% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`
`IF A>20 and <=60 THEN (IF B>=5% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`
`IF A>60 and <=150 THEN (IF B>=4% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`
`IF A>150 and <=500 THEN (IF B>=3% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`
`IF A>500 THEN (IF B>=5% OR C>=50%) = OUT, ELSE STAY`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula you are seeking.

```
=IF(AND(A1>500,OR(B1>5%,C1>=50%)),"OUT",IF(AND(AND(A1>150,A1<=500),OR(B1>=3%,C1>50%)),"OUT",IF(AND(AND(A1>60,A1<=150),OR(B1>=4%,C1>=50%)),"OUT",IF(AND(AND(A1>20,A1<=60),OR(B1>=5%,C1>=50%)),"OUT",IF(AND(A1<=20,OR(B1>=10%,C1>=50%)),"OUT","STAY")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `IF`, `AND` and `OR` statement in your Formula.

```
=IF(AND(A1>20;OR(B1>=10; C1>=50));"OUT";"STAY")
```

meaning that

IF (A1>20 AND (B1>=10 OR C1<=50)) THEN OUT ELSE STAY

etc..

Comment: This is working! :) And what is with the next condition? I mean, when A1>20 and <=60 then..... Does it look something like this:  =IF(AND(A1>20, A1<=60;OR(B1>=10; C1>=50));"OUT";"STAY")